# Find time slot in sql

Tags: sql-server

My table is below

```
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT(
ID INT,
A_START DATETIME,
A_END DATETIME,
CLINIC_ID INT
)
```

We have inserted following data

```sql
INSERT INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT VALUES(1,'2021-07-21 01:00:00','2021-07-21 02:00:00',1)

INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT VALUES(2,'2021-07-21 05:00:00','2021-07-21 06:00:00',1)

INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT VALUES(3,'2021-07-21 05:30:00','2021-07-21 06:30:00',1)

INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT VALUES(4,'2021-07-21 08:00:00','2021-07-21 09:00:00',1)

INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT VALUES(5,'2021-07-21 08:40:00','2021-07-21 09:40:00',1)

INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT VALUES(6,'2021-07-21 11:00:00','2021-07-21 12:00:00',1)
```

Expected result is

```
Slat start time      slat end time
2021-07-21 01:00:00 2021-07-21 02:00:00
2021-07-21 05:00:00 2021-07-21 06:30:00
2021-07-21 08:00:00 2021-07-21 09:40:00
2021-07-21 11:00:00 2021-07-21 12:00:00
```

Because in those record 2 and 3, 4 and 5 are intersect with each other.

I have tried, but unable to find expected result.

```sql
 SELECT * FROM APPOINTMENT 
     A,APPOINTMENT B
WHERE A.ID<>B.ID
AND (A.A_START<B.A_START AND A.A_START>B.A_END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/97b79/1

Comment: FYI, it's 2021; why are you *still* using that 1980's implicit JOIN syntax? The Explicit ANSI-92 JOIN syntax has been around for 29 years now, it's *long* past time you adopted it.

Comment: Do you NOT need to consider cliinc_id in your logic? Over-simplifying your sample data can mislead you and everyone else.

Comment: @SMor It will needed to assign staff for the particular clinic..  I have edited my question too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to compare intervals to check if they overlap is as follows:

```
a.Start < b.End AND a.End > b.Start
```

If you want to include cases where the two intervals butt-end each other, change `<` to `<=` and `>` to `>=`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM APPOINTMENT A
JOIN APPOINTMENT B ON A.ID <> B.ID
  AND (A.A_START < B.A_END AND A.A_END > B.A_START)
```

---

However, it appears this is completely not what you actually want. **You are actually just trying to merge overlapping intervals together.**

This type of problem is called *gaps-and-islands*, there are a number of different solutions.

This technique is fairly straight-forward:

- Identify the start of each group using `LAG`
- Use a running `COUNT` to create a grouping ID for each island
- Group by that grouping ID
- If you want to do this per some column, say `CLINIC_ID`, then you add that in a `PARTITION BY` clause in each `OVER`

```sql
WITH Prev AS (
    SELECT *,
      PrevEnd = LAG(A_END) OVER (ORDER BY A_START)
    FROM APPOINTMENT A
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(CASE WHEN PrevEnd >= A_START THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
        OVER (ORDER BY A_START ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM Prev
)
SELECT
  StartTime = MIN(A_START),
  ENdTime = MAX(A_END)
FROM Groupings
GROUP BY GroupId
ORDER BY StartTime;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3420c87d6d0f3cd5d3bdae156efa83f9)